# How does Haskell evaluate this function defined with partial application?

Tags: haskell, partial-application, equational-reasoning

I'm trying to understand how Haskell evalutes `pp1 [1,2,3,4]` to get `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]` here:

```
1. xnull f [] = []
2. xnull f xs = f xs
3. (/:/) f g x = (f x) (g x)
4. pp1 = zip /:/ xnull tail
```

I start like this:

```
a)  pp1 [1,2,3,4] = (zip /:/ xnull tail) [1,2,3,4]  -- (rule 4).
b)  (zip /:/ xnull tail) [1,2,3,4] 
       = (zip (xnull [1,2,3,4]) (tail) [1,2,3,4])   -- (rule 3)
c)  -- I'm not sure how to continue because xnull receives a function 
    -- and a param, and in this case it only receives a param.
```

Any help?

Comment: `xnull tail == drop 1`, `(/:/) == Control.Applicative.(<*>)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep expanding:

```
pp1 [1, 2, 3, 4] = zip /:/ xnull tail $ [1, 2, 3, 4]
                 -- inline (/:/) f g x = f x (g x)
                 --  f = zip, g = xnull tail, x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
                 -- therefore: 
                 = zip [1, 2, 3, 4] (xnull tail $ [1, 2, 3, 4])
                 -- inline the definition of xnull and note that the argument is not null
                 -- so we just want f x, or tail [1, 2, 3, 4]
                 = zip [1, 2, 3, 4] (tail [1, 2, 3, 4])
                 -- evaluate tail
                 = zip [1, 2, 3, 4] [2, 3, 4]
                 -- evaluate zip
                 = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Operator presidence matters. You didn't specify the associativity of `(/:/)` so it was defaulted to be relatively weak. Therefore, `(xnull tail)` bound tighter than `(/:/)`.

Also, as a side note, `(/:/)` already exists in the standard library as `(<*>)` from `Control.Applicative`. It's sufficiently general so this might be difficult to see, but the `Applicative` instance for `Reader` (or perhaps better understood as the function `Applicative`) provides this exact instance. It's also known as `ap` from `Control.Monad`.

```
zip <*> tail :: [b] -> [(b, b)]
zip <*> tail $ [1, 2, 3, 4] = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: I have a doubt.
Why is wrong this?

/:/ xnull tail [1,2,3,4] = xnull [1,2,3,4] (tail) [1,2,3,4] if I consider f as xnull, g as tail and x as [1,2,3,4]?

Thanks again!

Comment: Because of how function binding works. `xnull tail` binds more tightly than `(/:/ xnull)`. The reason is simply operator precedence rules -- function application (i.e. `xnull tail`) binds more tightly than operator application (i.e. `(/:/ xnull)`). You have some control over this, but that should only be exercised very carefully.

Comment: Ok, I understand that precedence is important for expression evaluation.

But what I don't understand are the expressions for f, g, and x when you apply rule number 3, f = ?, g = ? and x = ?

Thanks again!

Comment: Oh! that's a simpler question. f = `zip`, g = `xnull tail`, and x = `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer to explain the transformations I made in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong

```
b) (zip /:/ xnull tail) [1,2,3,4] = (zip (xnull [1,2,3,4]) (tail) [1,2,3,4]) (rule 3)
```

because it should be

```
b) (zip /:/ xnull tail) [1,2,3,4] = (zip [1,2,3,4] (xnull tail [1,2,3,4])) (rule 3)
```

The mistake lies in reading `zip /:/ xnull tail` as in `(zip /:/ xnull) tail` rather than `zip /:/ (xnull tail)`.

Comment: Why don't you need a `$` to get the `zip /:/ (xnull tail)` interpretation?

Comment: Because application binds more tightly than any infix operator: `f x ++ g x` is read as `(f x) ++ (g x)`, and `x ++**++ f x` is read as `(x) ++**++ (f x)`. Note that `$` follows this parsing rule, and `/:/` does as well.

Comment: @chi I have a doubt.
Why is wrong this?

/:/ xnull tail [1,2,3,4] = xnull [1,2,3,4] (tail) [1,2,3,4] if I consider f as xnull, g as tail and x as [1,2,3,4]?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Seba There's no `/:/ xnull tail [1,2,3,4]` in the first place because `(zip /:/ xnull tail)` means `(zip /:/ (xnull tail))`, because as chi points out, function application binds most tightly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has got a bit old. But anyway, here's my take..

It helps to see the definition

```
pp1 =  zip  /:/  xnull tail
    = (zip) /:/ (xnull tail)
    = (/:/) zip (xnull tail)
```

Note the parenthesizes around `(xnull tail)` indicating function application having higher precedence the infix operators.

Now the definition of `(/:/)` is to return another function `q` that would take an argument `x` and return the result of applying the function returned by partially applying its first argument `r` to what is returned from applying its second argument `s`.

That is `f` would need to be able to take at least 2 arguments, while `g` need only take at least 1.

```
(/:/) f g = q 
            where
            q x = r s
                  where
                  r = f x
                  s = g x
```

Note that `r` is `f x`, so `q x` is `f x s`.

It would have been clearer to write

```
f /:/ g = (\x -> f x (g x))
```

Now given

```
pp1 = zip /:/ xnull tail
```

we can expand to

```
pp1 = q
      where
      q x = r s
            where
            r = zip x
            s = xnull tail x
```

or

```
pp1 = (\x -> zip x $ xnull tail x)
```

The rest is just replacing `x` with `[1,2,3,4]` and do the evaluations.